# WordPress types plugin getting post's title instead of image's title

Tags: php, wordpress, image, custom-post-type

I'm using a wordpress plugin called [Types](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/types/).

I'm using their custom field capabilities to upload images into my gallery in my custom sidebar. I'm also using a lightbox to display these images.

So I'm trying get the title of each image to appear

```
<?php $resortimages = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wpcf-r-images'); 
foreach ($resortimages as $resortimage) {
echo '<li><a href="'. $resortimage. '" rel="lightbox" title="" ><img src="'. $resortimage. '"/></a></li>';
}
```

I've tried getting post title but it just gets the title of the post itself.

Answer (score 0):

Jesper, it looks like Types image field only stores image URL, not its contents. If you want to retrieve some other info (title, caption and description, for example), probably you'll have to try to get image ID by its URL. In your functions.php:

```
/**
 * Retrieve the attachment ID from its URL
 * 
 * @param string $image_url
 * @return int $attachment[0] The attachment ID
 *
 * @link http://pippinsplugins.com/retrieve-attachment-id-from-image-url/
 */
function mytheme_get_attachment_id( $image_url ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
    $attachment = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM " . $prefix . "posts" . " WHERE guid='%s';", $image_url ) ); 
        return $attachment[0]; 

}
```

After that, you can use you `foreach` and check for your IDs:

```
<?php
$resortimages = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wpcf-r-images'); 

foreach ($resortimages as $resortimage) {

    // Get attachment ID by its URL
    if ( $resortid = mytheme_get_attachment_id( $resortimage ) )
        $resortname = get_the_title($resortid);

    echo '<li><a href="'. $resortimage. '" rel="lightbox" title="' . $resorttitle . ' ><img src="'. $resortimage. '"/></a></li>';
}
?>
```

But beware of the number of queries that you'll do. Hope it helps!